# Closed form expression of an exponential sum from -n to n

Tags: summation

I'm looking for a way to write the following sum as a closed form expression:

$$
\sum_{n=-N}^{N} e^{cn*i}
$$

where $c$ is a constant and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

I found a closed form solution for $n= [0, N-1]$ at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFormulas.html , but I'm not sure how I can manipulate this to change the range from -N to N. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a geometric sequence. The first term is $e^{-cNi}$ and you keep multiplying by $e^{ci}$. You have $2N+1$ terms.
the sum is then $$e^{-cNi}\frac{1-e^{ci(2N+1)}}{1-e^{ci}}$$

Comment: Sorry, can you explain why I would be multiplying by $e^{-ci}$ with each iteration?

Comment: Sorry, its $e^{ci}$. I'll fix the answer

Comment: My fundamental knowledge is lacking in understanding why I would multiply for each iteration of a summation. Could you explain why I multiply and where $e^{ci}$ comes from? Thank you so much your answer.

Comment: The sum looks like $a_0+a_0r+a_0r^2+...$ Look at the ratio of two consecutive terms: $\frac{e^{c(n+1)i}}{e^{cni}}=e^{ci}$

Comment: Oh, I totally missed the connection to a geometric series. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: My summation begins at $n=-N$. Doesn't the geometric series necessarily start at 0?

Comment: Divide your sum by the term corresponding to $-N$. Then you can write it as a sum from $0$ to$2N+1$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=-N}^N e^{cni} = \sum_{n=-N}^0 e^{cni} + \sum_{n=1}^N e^{cni} = \sum_{n=0}^N e^{-cni} + \sum_{n=1}^N e^{cni} = \frac{1-e^{-ci(N+1)}}{1-e^{-ci}}+ e^{ci}\frac{1-e^{cNi}}{1-e^{ci}}$$

$$=\frac{1-e^{-ci(N+1)}}{1-e^{-ci}}+ \frac{e^{cNi}-1}{1-e^{-ci}} = \frac{e^{cNi}-e^{c(N+1)i}}{1-e^{-ci}} = -e^{c(N+1)i}$$